# Compressed Sensing with a Non-Invertible Sparsifying Transform

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

In "The Restricted Isometry Property and Its Implications for Compressed Sensing" (https://statweb.stanford.edu/~candes/papers/RIP.pdf), Candes describes the *Noisy Recovery* problem to be as follows (problem 1):
\begin{align}
  \text{minimize} & \hspace{1em} \| x \|_1 \\
  \text{subject to} & \hspace{1em} \|y - \Phi x \|_2 \leq \epsilon.
\end{align}

I am interested in the following problem (problem 2):
\begin{align}
  \text{minimize} &\hspace{1em} \| W x \|_1 \\
  \text{subject to} & \hspace{1em} \| y - \Phi x \|_2 \leq \epsilon.
\end{align}

If $W$ is invertible, then I can define $\tilde{x}=Wx$, which then becomes the following problem (in the form of problem 1):
\begin{align}
  \text{minimize} & \hspace{1em} \| \tilde{x} \|_1 \\
  \text{subject to} & \hspace{1em} \|y - \Phi W^{-1} \tilde{x} \|_2 \leq \epsilon.
\end{align}

However, what happens when $W$ is not invertible.  I can not find a way to convert the problem into the form of problem 1.  Are there theorems of compressed sensing related to this situation?  For example, if we know that the columns of $W$ are orthogonal, can that imply that $x$ will be recovered exactly?  When?

Comment: Just a marginal comment: if $W$ is a non-invertible square matrix, one might try to think about the consequences of considering the matrix $W + \epsilon I $ instead.

Comment: @gangrene  Thank you for your comment.  I don't think that (in general) that matrix satisfies the Restricted Isometry Property well, so I don't think that most of the theorems of compressed sensing apply.